# Tezos Account_Activate

Tags: node

"contents": [
                    {
                        "kind": "activate_account",
                        "pkh": "tz1hzjPPQK2X61z1CGvp2gmxNoXuhswYSqic",
                        "secret": "6a42379a705f04cca85b4d5d502a800515cc2684",
                        "metadata": {
                            "balance_updates": [
                                {
                                    "kind": "contract",
                                    "contract": "tz1hzjPPQK2X61z1CGvp2gmxNoXuhswYSqic",
                                    "change": "2400000000000"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]

For Account Activate - IN the Balance update Section , Does the "change Key" represent a Creadit amount to tz1hzjPPQK2X61z1CGvp2gmxNoXuhswYSqicto